# iterating a loop to give a new value if the previous value already exists in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, iteration, conditional-statements

I have a data frame with this information here:

```
df <- data.frame("string1" = c("ABECDE","ABECDE","ABECDE"), 
             "string2" = c("ABCD","ABCD","ABCD"),
             "site1" = NA, "site2" = NA, "combine" = NA, "filtered" = NA)
```

I would like to write a code that picks sites E and D in the string and adds them to the data frame.
If the combination is already created I'd like for it to go back and chose a new combination and check again until it gets one that has not been picked.

I have provided below the code I have done so far which gives the output of:

```
  string1 string2 site1 site2 combine filtered
1  ABECDE    ABCD    E3    D4    E3D4     E3D4
2  ABECDE    ABCD    E3    D4    E3D4     <NA>
3  ABECDE    ABCD    E3    D4    E3D4     <NA>
```

Here, E3D4 is the value you get when it first goes through the function.
I would now like for it to go back and pick the next possible combinations:
E6D4 and D5D4 for the next two lines but I have no idea how to properly structure the iteration.

Here is the code I have so far (there is probably a less redundant way to write it but I am a beginner so apologies if it is overly long)

```
#make the columns of string1 and string2 into vectors 
string1 <- df$string1
string2 <- df$string2

#for each string in the vector check to see first if it has an E, if not, then a D
#get the output as a letter and its position (eg E3)
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
if (grepl("E", string1[i])){
  sites1 = gregexpr('E', string1[i])
  df$site1 <- paste0(substring(string1[i], sites1[[1]][1], sites1[[1]][1]), sites1[[1]][1])
  } else if (grepl("D", string1[i])){
    sites = gregexpr('D', string1[i])
    df$site1 <- paste0(substring(string1[i], sites1[[1]][1], sites1[[1]][1]), sites1[[1]][1])
  }
}
#do the same for the second vector
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
if (grepl("E", string2[i])){
  sites2 <- gregexpr('E', string2[i])
  df$site2 <- paste0(substring(string2[i], sites2[[1]][1], sites2[[1]][1]), sites2[[1]][1])
} else if (grepl("D", string2[i])){
  sites2 <- gregexpr('D', string2[i])
  df$site2 <- paste0(substring(string2[i], sites2[[1]][1], sites2[[1]][1]), sites2[[1]][1])
}
}
#combine the sites
df$combine <- paste0(df$site1, df$site2)

#for each row of combined sites, check to see if the value is already created
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
  if(!df$combine[i] %in% df$filtered){
    df$filtered[i] <- df$combine[i]
  } else if(df$combine[i] %in% df$filtered){
    #go back to for loop and look for either another E in the list
    #if there is none, go to the next condition (looking for a D).
    #pick the next possible values, put them together and check again
    #do this continuously until you get a unique combine.
    #do this for string1 and then string2 (or alternating both, which ever is easier)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could simplify and try the following.

Create a custom function, that will detect all positions of "D" and "E" in your strings. Then use `expand.grid` to get all combinations of these positions. In your example data, this will include combinations of positions 3, 5, 6 with position 4 (in the end 3 combinations: (3, 4), (5, 4), and (6, 4)).

Then, you can go through each of these combinations and create the desired strings, by combining with `paste` the letter from the position with the position number. A list will hold these results and be assembled in the end with `rbind`.

There are a few questions that remain, including if there are situations when there are no "D" or "E" letters found.

```
my_fun <- function(x) {
  p1 <- as.numeric(unlist(gregexpr(pattern = 'D|E', x[["string1"]])))
  p2 <- as.numeric(unlist(gregexpr(pattern = 'D|E', x[["string2"]])))
  cbn <- expand.grid(p1, p2)
  lst <- list()
  for (i in seq_len(nrow(cbn))) {
    site1 <- paste0(substr(x[["string1"]], cbn[i, "Var1"], cbn[i, "Var1"]), cbn[i, "Var1"])
    site2 <- paste0(substr(x[["string2"]], cbn[i, "Var2"], cbn[i, "Var2"]), cbn[i, "Var2"])
    lst[[i]] <- c(string1 = x[["string1"]], string2 = x[["string2"]], site1 = site1, site2 = site2, combine = paste0(site1, site2))
  }
  return(as.data.frame(do.call("rbind", lst)))
}

do.call(rbind, apply(df, 1, my_fun))
```

I created example data to test this out:

```
  string1 string2 site1 site2 combine filtered
1  ABECDE    ABCD    NA    NA      NA       NA
2  AABCDE    ABCE    NA    NA      NA       NA
3  ABCDDE    ACDD    NA    NA      NA       NA
```

Which would give the following output:

```
   string1 string2 site1 site2 combine
1   ABECDE    ABCD    E3    D4    E3D4
2   ABECDE    ABCD    D5    D4    D5D4
3   ABECDE    ABCD    E6    D4    E6D4
4   AABCDE    ABCE    D5    E4    D5E4
5   AABCDE    ABCE    E6    E4    E6E4
6   ABCDDE    ACDD    D4    D3    D4D3
7   ABCDDE    ACDD    D5    D3    D5D3
8   ABCDDE    ACDD    E6    D3    E6D3
9   ABCDDE    ACDD    D4    D4    D4D4
10  ABCDDE    ACDD    D5    D4    D5D4
11  ABCDDE    ACDD    E6    D4    E6D4
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! the `expand.grid` function is very useful. need to tweak the order it picks the letters but that's no problem :)  Also there still should not be any strings without the letters I want.